# TestInitialize vs ClassInitialize

Tags: c#, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

What is the difference between `TestInitialize` vs `ClassInitialize` in MSTest?  What are the pros cons of each?

I'm under the impression that `TestInitialze` should run with EACH test, every time?  Is that correct?  And that `ClassInitialize` will run every time a new instance of any class?

Answer (score 121):

Both attributes are available only for the classes (and hence tests) where they belong.

`TestInitialize` runs **before every test** that is declared on the the **same class** where the attribute is declared.

`ClassInitialize` runs **only** on the initialization of the class where the attribute is declared. In other words it won't run for every class. Just for the class that contains the `ClassInitialize` method.

If you want a method that will run once before all tests or classes' initialization use the [`AssemblyInitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx).

Comment: What would be a usecase of ClassInitialize and AssemblyInitialize? I have a hard time to get an actual usecase for ClassInitialize...

Comment: One use case is when running integration tests for a DLL with an initialization method that takes a long time to run. ClassInitialize can be used to perform initialization at the start of the batch of tests, and ClassCleanup would call the DLL's terminate method.

Comment: Another case could be setting up objects with tons of injected dependencies and mock set-ups. I have some test classes with 100+ lines that would otherwise need to be in each test.

Comment: @DPH TestInitialize is good for repeated code, only if running the code takes long time, you will use ClassInitialize

Answer (score 0):

> Since ClassInitialize and ClassCleanUp are static, they are only executed once even though several instances of a test class can be created by MSTest.

You can read more about it here: [That Pesky MSTest Execution Ordering.. learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/nnaderi/that-pesky-mstest-execution-ordering)