# Initialise unit test class members upon declaration or in the TestInitialize method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, initializer

I understand that, when running unit tests, the class is instantiated for each test method.  Therefore, I see no difference in initialising members upon declaration versus in the **TestInitialize** method.  Is there anything particularly wrong about doing the former?

Note that this is a different question to [TestInitialize vs ClassInitialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999816/testinitialize-vs-classinitialize), although it technically might be similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestInitialize vs ClassInitialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999816/testinitialize-vs-classinitialize)

Comment: Depends if you need to re-initialise those values or set them up only one time.

Comment: @Sinatr Not quite. But it was because of that question I asked this one. I mean, what's the point of **ClassInitialize** if the class is instantiated for each test anyway?

Comment: @Ric Does that even matter for the purpose of this question? They could be reassigned whether initialised upon declaration or in **TestInitialize**.  Of course, at declaration, you have the added option of making it **readonly** to prevent reassignment.

Comment: Its upto you how  you want to organise your test class. Personally, if I define a member that gets used in every method, I tend to only reassign it in `TestInitialze` so I know that each method is getting the same default value, however it is changed hence `readonly` may not be suitable.

Comment: @Ric I think you're misunderstanding how unit tests are run, and therefore my question. I did mention it in my question, though - "the class is instantiated for each test method." Therefore, each test gets the same initialised value whether it was initialised upon declaration or in **TestInitialize**, even if a test reassigns it. I mentioned **readonly** for the 'upon declaration' case because this would protect against reassignment _within_ a test, but not for the purpose of protecting tests from each other (for the aforementioned reasons).

Comment: @Ric Try declaring a member `int x = 0` and put `Assert.IsTrue(++x == 0)` in each test. They'll all succeed.

Comment: Nope both (two tests) fail.

Comment: @Ric The fact they _both_ fail should have told you something. That was a typo by me, and the test was failing for a different reason to what we're discussing. Now if you change it to post-increment (i.e., `Assert.IsTrue(x++ == 0)`), or just change the `0` to `1`, you'll find they both succeed now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you use TestInitialize or the test class constructor to prepare each test? and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334515/do-you-use-testinitialize-or-the-test-class-constructor-to-prepare-each-test-an)

Comment: Avoid/minimise use of member variables, use local variables inside the test methods as much as possible. It will make each test more independent/separate/self-contained. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706008/is-it-a-good-practice-to-share-member-variables-among-unit-tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing wrong with initializing members in the declaration.

Primarily it comes down to preferred style. I prefer to make as many members `readonly` as I can, so I prefer initializing in the declaration when possible.

Others may prefer use of setup/teardown methods for all initialization and cleanup logic.

Comment: Exactly.  By initialising upon declaration, they can be made **readonly** which I also prefer (and is more defensive).