# Initialize private field for all unit tests at once

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Is there anyway that I could initialize my local variable once, for all unit tests, in the same class?

If I used `[TestInitialize()]`, the initialization happens once for each unit test, similarly if I use a constructor, it will be called once per test.

I thought of using `[ClassInitialize()]`, but this method has to be static and cannot access private fields.

```
[TestClass()]
public sealed class ElasticsearchTest
{
    private ElasticsearchClient _elasticClient;

    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void ClassInit()
    {
        // cannot do this... visual studio error: 
        // An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property
        _elasticClient = new ElasticsearchClient("http://localhost:9200", true);
    }

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        // this initialization happens once for each test
        _elasticClient = new ElasticsearchClient("http://localhost:9200", true);
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var res = _elasticClient.SearchDocuments("table");
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void Test2()
    {
        var res = _elasticClient.SearchDocuments("chair");

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestInitialize vs ClassInitialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999816/testinitialize-vs-classinitialize)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get test initialize in memory and use in each test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643532/how-to-get-test-initialize-in-memory-and-use-in-each-test)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim: The question that you are talking about is more recent than this question... if you think they are duplicate then that one is the more recent question.

Comment: "Possible duplicate" is a way to clean-up - to close similar questions and keep one with the best answers. The date is not essential. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha
If you agree that it requires clarification please vote on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281980/add-clarification-link-to-possible-duplicate-automated-comment

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim: I don't think they are duplicate anyways... I don't see any initialization of static variables there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard MS Test based solution to this problem is to use `[ClassInitialize]`. If you do this, you will also need to change the `private` variable to be `static`:

```
private static ElasticsearchClient _elasticClient;
```

Alternatively, consider using (instead of `[ClassInitialize]`):

```
private static ElasticsearchClient _elasticClient = new ElasticsearchClient("http://localhost:9200", true);
```