# MS UnitTestFramework retrieve and log exceptions c#

Tags: c#, log4net, microsoft-test-manager, vs-unit-testing-framework

I just started on a rather extensive automation project that uses MS's UnitTestFramework. One thing I noticed is that when there's an error in my code - not the app I test - the framework catches that error and fails the test in a nice happy way that allows for the test iteration to complete. However, I want to be able to see those exceptions & stack trace in my log4net logs, and so far I have found no way to grab them in my test cleanup (or anywhere outside of a try catch block which I have no intention of splattering in every method).

Anyone know how to get these exceptions into my logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [First-Chance Exception Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
 via the [AppDomain.FirstChanceException Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -

> This event is only a notification. Handling this event does not handle
>   the exception or affect subsequent exception handling in any way.
>   After the event has been raised and event handlers have been invoked,
>   the common language runtime (CLR) begins to search for a handler for
>   the exception. FirstChanceException provides the application domain
>   with a first chance to examine any managed exception.

So something like this (note it is in [a method marked as AssemblyInitialize, which means it runs once per test run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427443/global-test-initialize-method-for-mstest), and the code is excluding the AssertFailedException thrown by MSTest when a test fails. You might want to exclude other exceptions as well, as otherwise there could be a lot of 'noise' in the logs.)

```
[TestClass]
public class Initialize
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void InitializeLogging(TestContext testContext)
    {
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (source, e) =>
         {
           if (e.Exception is AssertFailedException == false)
                LogManager.GetLogger("TestExceptions").Error(e.Exception);
         };
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could give you more than 1 upvote, this has been driving me nuts. For anyone else who uses this solution, I threw this into the if to filter out noise since I really only need inner exceptions: e.Exception.InnerException != null

Answer (score 0):

If it feasible for you to replace the `[TestMethod]` attribute then you can define your own attribute `MyTestMethod`, say, by deriving from the default one like this:

```
public class MyTestMethodAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
{
    public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)
    {
        TestResult[] testResults = base.Execute(testMethod);
        foreach (var testResult in testResults.Where(e => e.Outcome == UnitTestOutcome.Failed))
            testResult.LogOutput += $"Exception `{testResult.TestFailureException.GetType().Name}` with message `{testResult.TestFailureException.Message}`.";
        return testResults;
    }
}
```

The following test then produces the expected log message `Exception TestFailedException with message Assert.Fail failed. Some exception text.` in the standard output panel of Visual Studio's Test Explorer.

```
[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
    [MyTestMethod]
    public void Test()
        => Assert.Fail("Some exception text");
}
```

The approach also works when tests execute in parallel.